# Does age matter when it comes to tennis skills?

Tags: tennis-club-story

I'm trying to recruit a world class player as my doubled partner.  Sometimes I find one but they may be an old person or a kid.  Does this affect their attributes in some way that would make them a worse tennis player?

Comment: Also can someone please retag and make tennis-club-story I'm on mobile and can't make the tag

Comment: @z ' Tag has been added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, neither age nor sex affects performance in this game.  That superstar grandma has as much of a chance of winning the 4 majors as a normal superstar adult male.

The only time age/sex matters is that some clubs will only play against old or female opponents.